# IPMI: Chassis and BMC fail selftest, how can I fix this?

Tags: linux, ipmi

I've got an Intel linux cluster with IPMI interfaces on the nodes. Lately, the IPMI interfaces have been acting flaky. For example, I can no longer use IPMI commands to get the nodes to PXE boot, and rebooting them via IPMI works sometimes but not always.

I recently discovered that you can test the chassis and BMC with ipmitool, and this was the output:

```
# ipmitool chassis selftest
Self Test Results    : device error
                       [FRU Internal Use Area corrupted]

# ipmitool bmc selftest
Selftest: device corrupted
Internal Use Area corrupted
```

It looks like something has gone wrong. Is there any way to restore the IPMI interfaces to their original state? 
(Note that I don't know what the specific IPMI hardware is here, or how to query them to find out).

Answer (score 1):

Reflashing the firmware/BIOS might help... or hard power cycling the machine - unplugging it completely.

What type of machines are they?

Comment: They are Penguin Relion 2612 servers. Tried to unplug completely, but problem wasn't resolved.

Comment: Ah, sorry... never used Penguin hardware :(

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to verify this on other machines of the same type - it's quite possible that all of your systems of the same type have some sort of ipmi oddity that ipmitool is failing to deal with correctly.

Comment: Out of ten nodes, it works on two of them, fails on eight. It used to work, but started to fail a few months ago, and I don't htink there was a software change.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ipmitool reset warm` or `ipmitool reset cold` can sometimes help.

Comment: Interestingly, many implementations log to RAM, and they log every access. If the RAM gets full, things may react odd (at least). Resetting those beasts usually clears the RAM.